# Calling a JavaScript function, which is inside a string, and concatenating params with a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to achieve this? My code below doesn't work:

```
$("#template-1")
    .find("span")
    .html("<div id='dialog'><input type='file' onchange='LoadImage(this,"+ 
        canvas +")' id='t1-1-img-header'/><canvas class='dialogCanvas'"+ 
        "width='475' height='250' style='border: 1px solid #555; "+
        "margin-top:10px'></canvas></div>");
```

On the code above, I'm trying to pass "this" and a variable, which is filled somewhere else, to the function "LoadImage". Everything is being created dynamically and is inside this long string.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it was a very stupid question.

```
Edit: The variable "canvas" is a string with an id name 
I'm getting somewhere else. And it's the id for a canvas element.
```

**Edit 2:**
I'm sorry to be answering to my own post, but I couldn't flag the answer that helped me the most (by @Santiago Rebella), so I'm copying it here.

```
onchange='LoadImage(this,\""+ canvas +"\")'
```

Turns out that, by escaping it, the code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be working just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/zE22f/

Comment: What is the value of `canvas`? It needs to be a string, since you're concatenating it to a string.

Comment: isnt going to be converted to string anyway as is being added to a string?

Comment: @SantiagoRebella It will, but it's string representation will be meaningless to the handler.

Comment: @plalx so then it should be onchange='LoadImage(this,\""+ canvas +"\")' id='t1-1-img-header'/>. could that be the problem?

Comment: @SantiagoRebella We don't even know what `canvas` is in the question. I expected it was an `HTMLCanvasElement`. It it's not and it's a canvas `id` then you would be correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't flag the answer that helped me the most (by @Santiago Rebella), so I'm copying it here.
 

    onchange='LoadImage(this,\""+ canvas +"\")' id='t1-1-img-header'/>

Turns out that, by escaping it, the code worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*The answer below assumes that `canvas` is a reference to a `HTMLCanvasElement` object.*

You cannot store an object reference in a string. However you can always store something useful that allows to retrieve the object, like it's `id`, but there's a better solution.

Your main problem is that you are trying to deal with inline handlers, which should usually be avoided.

You can use jQuery to parse your HTML string, query the created DOM element for the element you are looking for and attach the event handler to it.

E.g.

```
var $myEl = $('<div><input type="text"></div>')
    .find('input')
    .on('change', function (e) {
        console.log(this); //the input
        console.log(canvas); //use the canvas variable (not declared in this example)

        //if you want to access the canvas next to the input in your example
        //you could do $(this).next('canvas');
    });

$('#content').append($myEl); //append your element rather than setting innerHTML
```